# MacBook Pro 13 with Retina display consumes 10% battery overnight with the lid closed, is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I bought a MacBook Pro 13 Retina nearly a month ago. Talking to a friend he told me that is not normal for this pc to consume 10% battery over night with the lid closed and with "Power Nap" disabled.

Is it true? And if it is in fact true, is this problem covered by the warranty?

This is the log what i get from the `pmset -g log | grep ' Wake '` command

```
2016-09-22 23:05:30 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=34664]           
2016-09-22 23:25:24 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(346 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(535 ms)]           
2016-09-22 23:25:56 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=33438]           
2016-09-22 23:42:33 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(309 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(531 ms)]           
2016-09-22 23:42:39 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=32436]           
2016-09-23 00:03:05 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(404 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(445 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(541 ms)]           
2016-09-23 00:03:37 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=31177]           
2016-09-23 00:18:38 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(346 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(533 ms)]           
2016-09-23 00:18:43 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=30271]           
2016-09-23 00:39:07 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(368 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(533 ms)]           
2016-09-23 00:39:39 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=29015]           
2016-09-23 00:54:41 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(404 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(312 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(532 ms)]           
2016-09-23 00:54:46 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7200] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=28108]           
2016-09-23 01:15:07 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(399 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(637 ms)]           
2016-09-23 01:15:39 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=26855]           
2016-09-23 01:30:41 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(404 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(307 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(533 ms)]           
2016-09-23 01:30:46 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=25948]           
2016-09-23 01:51:08 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(398 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(632 ms)]           
2016-09-23 01:51:40 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=24694]           
2016-09-23 02:06:42 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(308 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(534 ms)]           
2016-09-23 02:06:47 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=23787]           
2016-09-23 02:27:09 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(356 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(536 ms)]           
2016-09-23 02:27:41 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=22533]           
2016-09-23 02:42:43 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(404 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(347 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(535 ms)]           
2016-09-23 02:42:48 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=21626]           
2016-09-23 03:03:09 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(403 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(638 ms)]           
2016-09-23 03:03:41 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=20373]           
2016-09-23 03:18:43 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(308 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(530 ms)]           
2016-09-23 03:18:48 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=19466]           
2016-09-23 03:39:10 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(401 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(405 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(637 ms)]           
2016-09-23 03:39:42 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=18212]           
2016-09-23 03:54:44 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(308 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(530 ms)]           
2016-09-23 03:54:49 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=17305]           
2016-09-23 04:15:11 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(407 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(636 ms)]           
2016-09-23 04:15:43 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=16051]           
2016-09-23 04:30:44 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(310 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(530 ms)]           
2016-09-23 04:30:49 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=15145]           
2016-09-23 04:51:11 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(359 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(401 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(533 ms)]           
2016-09-23 04:51:43 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=13891]           
2016-09-23 05:06:44 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(405 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(348 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(536 ms)]           
2016-09-23 05:06:49 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=12985]           
2016-09-23 05:27:10 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(363 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(407 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(542 ms)]           
2016-09-23 05:27:42 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=11732]           
2016-09-23 05:42:43 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(405 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(307 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(531 ms)]           
2016-09-23 05:42:48 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=10826]           
2016-09-23 06:03:10 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(398 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(634 ms)]           
2016-09-23 06:03:42 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=9572]           
2016-09-23 06:18:44 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(308 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(532 ms)]           
2016-09-23 06:18:49 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=8665]           
2016-09-23 06:39:10 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(395 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(634 ms)]           
2016-09-23 06:39:42 +0300 Wake Requests         [*proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=7412]           
2016-09-23 06:54:44 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(308 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(532 ms)]           
2016-09-23 06:54:50 +0300 Wake Requests         [proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=6505]           
2016-09-23 07:15:11 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(330 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(624 ms)]           
2016-09-23 07:15:43 +0300 Wake Requests         [proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=5251]           
2016-09-23 07:30:45 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(403 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(349 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(535 ms)]           
2016-09-23 07:30:50 +0300 Wake Requests         [proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7199] [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=4344]           
2016-09-23 07:51:11 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(360 ms)] [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(534 ms)]           
2016-09-23 07:51:43 +0300 Wake Requests         [proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=3091]           
2016-09-23 08:06:31 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using BATT (Charge:54%)           
2016-09-23 08:06:31 +0300 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [SSP3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(402 ms)] [AirPort_Brcm4360 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(309 ms)] [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(427 ms)] [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(529 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(611 ms)]
```

**Update:**

What I tried so far:

1.Updating the OS from El Capitan to Sierra

2.Reinstalling the OS

3.Changed my router form D-link to Cisco

4.Resetting the SMC and PRAM

5.Putting the pc in safe mode

**Update 2 :**

After talking to Apple costumer services they told me too:

1.Remove a program called Dropbox.

2.Remove an extensions from Safari, in my case It was an addblocking one.

3.Try to create a test user to see if the battery still drains.

**Update 3 :**

After talking to Apple costumer services for several times, they couldn't pinpoint the problem so they told me to have my pc checked for hardware problems. Thing I will do after my school exams ends...

The problem still persist's even after this steps.

Comment: Sitting overnight with the lid closed it should consume almost 0 battery.  Make sure you've reviewed your Power settings and see if anything is running overnight.  Also, check if you have anything connecting to the MBP that could be reaching-out to it at night and causing it to wake-up and respond.

Comment: I did review my power settings, I also updated to sierra and but nothing changed. And because I updated to sierra now i cant do syslog for some reasons :/

Comment: Looks like your MBP is waking up to show some sort of notification, are there any notifications on the screen when you wake the machine up in the morning?

Comment: Just the weather one i think, havent checked as i dont really use this feature! Do you think i should go in "do not disturb" mode?

Comment: What's all those com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub messages?  Is there something connected via USB?

Comment: "Sitting overnight" is a pretty subjective term.  For me, that means 2am to 6am.  Can you be more specific?  How old is the MBP?  What model? From your logs, it's waking every 20 mins or so to check something over WiFi which requires power.  So far, things look somewhat "normal"

Comment: Well, in this case overnigh is  from 23:00 to 8:00. And it's a Macbook Pro 13 retina and is just 1month old thats whats actually bothering me so much. It shouldnt loose so much bat at such a young age...

Comment: @fbara no nothing, all program closed and no usb or cables attached ...

Comment: Have you considered installing 10.10? (unless you need software that runs only on 10.11 or "better", such as xcode)

Comment: I did add to the answer below with more things you should confirm.  The comments here from others are right-on, it's obviously connecting to something, but also it could be broken, for example a search on google for "AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub" yields completely nothing for me.

Comment: I saw [this thread on Apple's site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7010693?start=165&tstart=0) and it's similar to your issue.  There's about 15 pages of info, too much for me to review.  Maybe you'll find helpful info there?

Comment: hi p3rand0r please keep us all updated how it is going

Comment: @forgotstackxpassword sorry for the delay, i busy lately, so long story short i talked to an apple senior costumer support more on the updated post!

Comment: Yes, thanks; running the programs "Drop Box" and Safari, would definitely cause Network traffic!  That's really valuable info; make sure Drop box is completely uninstalled, from `/Applications` or any where else, and that nothing Drop Box-related is in `$USER/LaunchAgents,` `$USER/LaunchDaemons,` `/Library/LaunchAgents,` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons,` or Start Up Items in your Users & Groups setting for your users.  Just post or search more if you need help to completely get rid of Drop Box.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is the macOS continues to check for updates (including email, software, news, etc.) while your MacBook Pro is asleep (this feature is called "[Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204032)"). This means it's very quick to get up and running when you open your MacBook, but it also means your battery goes down while it's asleep.

The problem some people have is that even with "Power Nap" disabled, their battery still goes down as MacOS continues to check for updates (it's possibly other software checking online for things).

To fix this, you can tell you MacBook Pro to disconnect from the Internet while it's asleep, preventing online checks.

To do this, you need to set the `tcpkeepalive` setting to `0`.

Open up Terminal and type:

```
sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0
```

After you enter your password for sudo it gives you a warning saying some features may not work properly. This is fine, it simply disables Internet access during sleep.

You can check it is set correctly by running:

```
pmset -g
```

Which should show "`tcpkeepalive 0`"

And you can, of course, reverse it at any time by running:

```
sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 1
```

Simple!

Note: You can also force your Mac not to connect to the Internet when it's asleep *even when connected to a power supply*, if you like: `sudo pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0`. (Personally I don't mind as long as it's not using my battery, so `-b` is fine for me.)

Also note: The results from `pmset -g` will vary depending on if your MacBook Pro is connected to power or not *when you run the command*. It will reflect the *current* `tcpkeepalive` setting, depending on its current power situation.

Comment: Wanted to add a recent data point that this method works! Macbook Pro 13 late-2016 with High Sierra 10.13.1. I was losing 10-20% charge overnight while the laptop was in sleep and not plugged in. Grepping the logs for 'Sleep' showed it going back to Maintenance sleep every 10-15 minutes. AFTER this fix, I put it to sleep at 100%; 12 hours later I woke it up and still 100%. Very glad to have this resolved, thanks!

Comment: @brism Yep. It's still working on my Mid-2015 MacBook Pro Retina, too.

Comment: It works on my Late-2013 MacBook Pro Retina with MacOSX Mojave v10.14.2

Comment: Seems to be working on Catalina, at least disconnecting from wifi when screen sleeps. Great job!

Comment:  Hey there. Wondering why you reverted the change to add more software specifics (Find My, Power Nap) from this answer. Seems it would be help others when they are googling "pmset Power Nap doesn't work" Edit here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/294714/revisions#spacer-cd10f674-4ace-48ee-bbeb-81a2fb88292b

Comment: @BeauSmith Because your edit was wrong. The feature itself is called "Power Nap" (see: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204032). Also this question is not about "Power Nap" not working. Furthermore, the original question mentions "Power Nap" so there's no reason to mention it again purely for SEO purposes (although I have edited the question to mention it, to make things clearer).

Comment: I wonder if you could share with us where you find Apple's documentation covering use of the `tcpkeepalive`  option in `pmset`? It's not in `man pmset` AFAICT - at least not on Catalina or Mojave or High Sierra.

Comment: `tcpkeepalive` is not addressed in `man pmset` - or anywhere else I can find. And so I wondered if you knew something

Comment: @Seamus You can see the setting for yourself by typing `pmset -g`. `man pmset` was last updated in November 2012. TCP stands for Transmission Control Protocol. It's the fundamental protocol used to send data over the internet. Keeping TCP connections alive means they are free to send and receive data while macOS is "asleep". Turning it off prevents that. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial, but you are still missing the point: Apple has made choices regarding how TCP KeepAlives operate in various power conservation modes (e.g. "Power Nap", Sleep, Standby, etc), but they have not documented those choices. The label `tcpkeepalive` is not mentioned in `man pmset`. So - how do **you** know that it is working for all processes when in sleep mode?

Comment: And wrt the Wikipedia article you referenced, there's this: *"keepalives are an optional feature, and if included must default to off"*. Don't know about your systems of course, but in all of mine (except an old 2011 Macbook running High Sierra), `pmset` reports `tcpkeepalive` as `1` - which I *guess* is enabled. And there's no need continuing this - I simply asked if you could share your source for Apple's documentation on `tcpkeepalive` - you've not done that, so I'll assume that you - like me - are operating without it.

Comment: I find my safari web browsing became noticeably slow after using `sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0`. By looking at the comment, seems Safari now is making a new TCP connection every time, thus the slowdown. So I reverted it back.

Comment: @Seamus I missed your messages. Apple explain this themselves as you will have seen when you typed in the above: "Warning: This option disables TCP Keep Alive mechanism when system is sleeping. This will result in some critical features like 'Find My Mac' not to function properly.)."

Answer (score 9):

***Update : This doesn't work with Catalina, see Django Reinhardt's answer instead.***

I was suffering the same issue before, my MBP 2015's battery was draining slowly but when I don't use it so frequently, this caused so much pain.
This method helped me so much; now I can go out with my Mac with 20% charge and make my day.
There is a significant difference between MacBook Pro 2015 and the previous models of MacBook Pros. You can check these settings by this command line;

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformFeatureDefaults
```

The output on your mac would be like this;

> {"TCPKeepAliveDuringSleep"=Yes,"DNDWhileDisplaySleeps"=No,"TCPKeepAliveExpirationTimeout"=43200,"NotificationWake"=Yes}

To make your MBP sleep deep like the old versions you should first restart your computer into recovery mode. To do that you should restart your mac and hold CMD+R until you hear the start up sound.
After that open terminal and type this;

```
csrutil disable
```

Then restart your MacBook again.
Go to this destination, you can access inside kext files by right clicking -> Show Package Contents
  /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/X86PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources

Find your board id with:

```
ioreg -l | awk '/board-id/{print $4}' | sed 's/[<">]//g'
```

Open <your_board_id>.plist (e.g. Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6.plist) file by a text editor and edit these settings just like these;

```
<key>TCPKeepAliveDuringSleep</key>
<false/>
<key>NotificationWake</key>
<false/>
<key>DNDWhileDisplaySleeps</key>
<true/>
```

TCPKeepAliveDuringSleep keeps your MacBook connections open when its sleeping, so it keep Wifi connected.
NotificationWake wakes your Mac randomly to check notifications especially make this one false.
DNDWhileDisplaySleeps means "Do not disturb on sleep"; MacBook does get disturbed by notifications when it's asleep.

My personal opinion is this process should be done by every 2015+ MacBook user because MacBooks are not cell phones that ring for notifications. Apple should have made a toggle button for this.

Do not forget to enable System Integrity Protection again. You should restart into recovery mode and on terminal type "csrutil enable" and restart.

**UPDATE:** This reportedly no longer works with the latest versions of macOS. See [this MacRumors article](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/psa-if-your-2015-or-2016-mbp-has-some-battery-drain-while-sleeping-here-is-the-fix.2026702/page-3#post-24519234) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

This is **not normal**, but it is, at the least, very clear in the logs that there are ACK packets being processed, and your wireless card is preventing the laptop from sleeping normally. The logs are in line with [developer notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html) for events available to make the computer wake up, and log that it is "slow", so far example, as OzzieSpin said in a comment above, your computer is waking up *abnormally*--unless (as also several comments above discussed, it is trying to connect with something)--for example verify, **bluetooth is off,** **nothing is connect to the computer in any way**, including the **SD card slot**,the computer was **not connected** to any type of server e.g. smb shared-drives or ldap, and there are no programs at all running (*yes*, including Safari, or Drop Box, which *both could cause exactly these symtoms*), including those you don't expect (see for example your "start-up" items under *Users & Groups* in System Preferences, and $USER/Library/LaunchAgents). Would you please post the output of `sudo ifconfig`?

**You can verify this by looking at [this nearly identical post on Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html)**, where the OP comes back after receiving Apple support, and decides that the **issue was an incompatible wireless access point or router**, and a firmware upgrade on the router solved the issue, apparently.  **That link as well as [this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201714), contains long lists of things you need to check, directly from Apple,** and

> I would be surprised if your issue doesn't go away after walking
>   through those posts alone.

Moving on a bit further, the usual action, if I had not seen those posts would be to reset your SMC ([instructions by model, here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)), and PRAM. Plug in your laptop to the wall, close all applications/save your data, then hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the power button. The screen should turn off instantly. Then, wait 10 seconds. Next, while it is off, hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then press the power button. Keep holding those buttons until you hear the chime, the screen lights up, then turns off again.  After ensuring you'd turned off services (see the links above), and then reset the hardware, you could mostly eliminate the computer as the sole source of the issue.

As a side note here, since Sierra literally just came out, then depending on your situation, you might wait until the bugs are worked out a bit before upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less invasive solution that worked for me: enable Do Not Disturb while while the MacBook is sleeping.

1. Open System Preferences -> Notifications
2. Under the Do Not Disturb section, add a check mark next to "When the display is sleeping"

Comment: Done that, the problem still persist !