# Macbook not sleeping when lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I bought a M1 Macbook Pro in December, really happy with the laptop so far, especially the battery. Lately though, I've been noticing faster battery drain when sleeping. I thought that maybe there was an issue with the device failing to go to sleep when closing the lid.

I just used the command **pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "** to check the sleeping behaviour pattern. Here are the results:

```
2021-03-07 17:57:13 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:33%) 135 secs  
2021-03-07 18:00:13 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:33%) 16 secs   
2021-03-07 18:00:29 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 lid/HID Activity Using BATT (Charge:33%) 252 secs  
2021-03-07 18:04:41 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 144 secs  
2021-03-07 18:07:50 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 144 secs  
2021-03-07 18:10:59 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 143 secs  
2021-03-07 18:14:07 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 138 secs  
2021-03-07 18:17:10 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 120 secs  
2021-03-07 18:19:55 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 133 secs  
2021-03-07 18:22:53 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 131 secs  
2021-03-07 18:25:49 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 149 secs  
2021-03-07 18:29:03 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 139 secs  
2021-03-07 18:32:07 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 148 secs  
2021-03-07 18:35:20 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 132 secs  
2021-03-07 18:38:17 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 156 secs  
2021-03-07 18:41:38 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 139 secs  
2021-03-07 18:44:42 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 139 secs  
2021-03-07 18:47:46 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 150 secs  
2021-03-07 18:51:01 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 138 secs  
2021-03-07 18:54:04 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 133 secs  
2021-03-07 18:57:02 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 143 secs  
2021-03-07 19:00:10 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 151 secs  
2021-03-07 19:03:26 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 138 secs  
2021-03-07 19:06:29 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 125 secs  
2021-03-07 19:09:19 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 134 secs  
2021-03-07 19:12:18 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:32%) 629 secs  
2021-03-07 19:22:51 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVAP] : due to Notification Using AC (Charge:32%) 4 secs    
2021-03-07 19:22:55 +0100 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:32%) 2 secs
```

This is just a snapshot but it goes on and on, the same Entering Sleep state... message appears every minute, at least until one week ago. Is this normal?

I noticed that after installing Amphetamine, I tried it for a bit, but since I wasn't using it a lot, I uninstalled it. Did it mess up the system?

Comment: Same thing on my M1 Air. It drains to 1 percent overnight, lid closed. Same logs: `Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:41%) 7 secs`. Check this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253776/macbook-pro-13-with-retina-display-consumes-10-battery-overnight-with-the-lid-c